# Why at sign will be replaced as question mark in sms text message?

Tags: c#, .net, sms, smtpclient

I am working on a C# application that will send SMS message to customer by using smtp service. Currently, the at sign will be replaced with question mark both in message body and message subject. I try many kinds of encoding such as unicode, UTF-8, UCS-2, ASCII but either can work well. Does anyone know how to avoid it?

```
 var mailMessage = new MailMessage
 {
       IsBodyHtml = true,
       SubjectEncoding = Encoding.Unicode,
       Subject = "@@" + subject + "@@",
       BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
       Body = messageBody ?? "",
       From = new MailAddress(from, "My Name"),
 };
  using (var smtpClient = new SmtpClient())
 {
      using (mailMessage)
      {
         smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);
      }
 }
...
```

Comment: Do you know what platform is converting the email to SMS?

Comment: I guess it depended the inner implementation of .NET library.

Answer (score 1):

Your code most likely is not to blame; and is most likely a true case of *Lost in Translation*

- The encoding used by the majority of the cell-phones in the world for SMS is [GSM 03.38](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GSM_03.38) which is not something found outside of the phones and the respective carriers.
- The standard encoding for email is ASCII with optional UTF-8 support.

The problem you are having is the translation between the 2 standards when you cross the bridge from SMTP (email) to SMS, which is not part of your code. It is most likely a free service being provided by the phone carrier. This is something that most likely will not get fixed by them as there is no money in it.

It also appears to have been known for quite some time. If we go back 5 years ago we can find this SO post: [converting Twilio sms body to a string - encoding error for @ symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11353449/converting-twilio-sms-body-to-a-string-encoding-error-for-symbol) which sounds mighty similar to what you are experiencing.

So, the only real possible fix is going to leave the realm of using SMTP to send text messages. There are many SMS Gateway services that you can use to send the messages via relatively easy API's. They may cost money but as they say; you get what you pay for